# jQuery validation plugin addMethod firing incorrectly

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I must be missing something obvious, but everything that I've tried for this is leaving me empty handed, so I'm a bit puzzled.

I'm attempting to use the jQuery validation plugin with custom validation methods, but it seems to be hit or miss. It seems that I am able to successfully add rules to a certain extent, but some of the methods are not applied. Or the specified method is not applied, and the incorrect method is instead applied.

So, for example, this works without a hitch:

```
$.validator.addMethod("emailValidation",
    function(value, element) {
        return /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/.test(value);
    },
    "Please enter a valid email address."
);
$.validator.addMethod("password",
    function(value, element) {
        return /[^\s]{6,25}/.test(value);
    },
    "Please enter a password between 6 and 25 characters long."
);
...
$(function(){
    $("#registrationForm").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                emailValidation: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                password: true
            },
        }
    });
});
```

Both the password validation and email validation work.

But then I add, in the same exact manner, a validation test for names. So, right below where the password method ends, I add:

```
$.validator.addMethod("name",
    function(value, element) {
        return /[^\s]{6,25}/.test(value);
    },
    "Please enter a valid name."
);
```

Which turns the validate call into:

```
$(function(){
    $("#registrationForm").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                emailValidation: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                password: true
            },
            studentFirstName: {
                name: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And suddenly, everything is only validating for names. Both the email and password fields now validate using the name method, as does the name field.

This is confusing! I've added console.log calls to all methods, and indeed, it's not that one is being called after the other - the only one being called is name.

I've checked and double checked that the element selection is good. I've checked that everything is groovy with the methods themselves. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if `name` is a reserved word but since the plugin uses the `name` attribute to keep track of inputs, perhaps you should use more creative names for your custom method.  In other words, does it start working if you change `name` to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if `name` is a reserved word in JavaScript but since the plugin uses the name attribute to keep track of inputs, perhaps you should use a more creative word for naming your custom method.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the answer was every bit as obvious and trivial as I imagined it would be.

"name" is a jQuery validation plugin keyword. It's protected. You can't use it. As soon as I changed the name of the method to, say, "validateName," everything went off without a hitch.

...I can't believe I wasted an hour on this.

Thank you, Sparky, for your suggestion.